# Array Length, why can't it be used when taking from command lines?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, command-line

I'm trying to get one of my argv's (which is an `int` sent in as a string), to become the length of an array, but the compiler keeps telling at me that *num_of _players* isn't constant and cant be used.
Any suggestions why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int num_of_players = stoi(argv[argc - 1]);
    int player_list[num_of_players];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because it is not a compile-time known value. Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: @hellow: ⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️

Comment: Well, at least you're using a compiler that gives an error, thus preventing you from falling into the VLA trap.  Too many new C++ programmers use compilers that by default, accepts this non-C++ syntax, which leads them into believing what is being written is valid C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that declaring arrays in that way requires the size to be provided at compile time. They can not be declared with a value discovered at runtime.

The most basic alternative is to use a *dynamic array* which you can create manually:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int num_of_players = stoi(argv[argc - 1]);
    int* player_list = new int[num_of_players];

    // do stuff with player_list here...

    delete[] player_list; // REMEMBER to delete[] it!!

    return 0;
}
```

When you create something (like an array) using `new` or `new[]` you have to manually dispose of them (incl. give the memory back) using `delete` or `delete[]` respectively. However this can be forgotten so it is a potential source of memory leaks. For that reason one would typically use a type that *manages* the dynamic array automagically like a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3):

Because it isn't constant and can't be used.

Like how the size of an `int` is baked into your program, so is the size of an array. It has 3 elements, or 9 elements, or 512 elements … but this information cannot come from the command-line because it already had to be baked into your program when you compiled it.

Instead, use a "dynamic array" like `std::vector` that can grow and shrink as needed at runtime.

Comment: i understand using std::vector will help, however i have been set limitations, and cant use vector :(

Comment: @Xenheart Then you'll have to fake a vector using `new`. Discovering this was probably the purpose of the assignment. Did the professor not yet teach you the features needed to solve it?